# c# Linq Data grid view column checking if null

Tags: c#, linq

I need check if the value in **GridView** is null or empty using **System.Linq** and **DataSet**.

I have tried this code without success because the error is :

> Specified cast is not valid.

How to do resolve this?

My code below.

Thank you in advance or any help.

```
gv.Columns[4].FooterText = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("Tot1")).Where(x => x != null).Sum().ToString();
```

SQL Query:

```
sql = " SELECT IFNULL(Tot1,0) AS Tot1
sql += " FROM ";
sql += "    doTable; ";

+------+
| Tot1 |
+------+
|  0   |
|  0   |
|  1   |
|  0   |
|  2   |
+------+
```

Comment: `Int32` cannot be `null` and if field is not of that type then it throws this `InvalidCastException`. Check what you get with `String.Join(";", gv.Columns[4].FooterText = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x == null ? "<null>" : x.GetType().Name))`

Comment: You are providing way to little information to answer your question comprehensively. Yor problem probably is in `x.Field<Int32>("Tot1")`, as there is the only place i see a possible cast.

Comment: @Sefe Thank you for reply. In my SQL query (db MySQL) I have try                 >  IFNULL(Tot1,0) AS Tot1

Comment: You should try to apply filter first: *gv.Columns[4].FooterText = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x["Tot1"] != null).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Tot1"])).Sum().ToString();*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `long` for your casting, as `IFNULL` return `BIGINT` from MySQL.

```
gv.Columns[4].FooterText = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x.Field<long?>("Tot1")).Where(x => x != null).Sum().ToString();
```

A nicer version would be:

```
gv.Columns[4].FooterText = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x.Field<long?>("Tot1") ?? 0).Sum().ToString();
```